# How does Bash modulus/remainder work?

Tags: bash, expression, modulus

Can somebody explain how it works? I just don't understand it. Why we get 2 from

```
expr 5 % 3
```

or 1 from

```
expr 5 % 4
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x % y gives you the remainder of x/y.

For example, 3 goes into 5 one time.  if you subtract 3 from 5, it gives 2. This is what is left over.

In 7 % 3, 3 goes into 7 twice (3*2 < 7, 3*3 > 7). If you subtract 3*2, or 6 from 7, you get one.

`7 % 3 == 1`

Answer (score 1):

Modulo/modulus is the remainder of the integer division operation. In your first example:

```
5 % 3
```

This evaluates to `2` because dividing 5 by 3 leaves 2 remaining.

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another.

5 / 3 = 1 remainder 2

5 / 4 = 1 remainder 1